# How to measure the throughput (packet/sec) of the RYU controller in mininet

Tags: mininet, sdn, ryu

I am trying to measure the throughput of controller in packets/sec. Is there any idea about it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count/record the packets, why not use `tcpdump`? Let's say you have the following topology:

```
H1 - - - - - | |- - - - - H3
             S 1 
H2 - - - - - | |- - - - - H4
```

F.e., all hosts are connected to S1. You can then run tcpdump on S1 and it will capture all packets going through your network